# Node.Js Async usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

My `Process1()` function has a database loop, so `Process2()` and `Process3()` calling more than once. Which function should I use in [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async), to wait for a `for loop`?

```
 async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        Process1(yyy, function(){
            //process1 function has a for loop.
            callback();
        })
    },
    function(callback){
       Process2(function(){
            // so process2() is calling more than once
            callback();
        })
    }
], function (callback) {
     Process3()
});
```

Process1() :

```
function Process1(yyy, pass){
user.find({}).exec(function(e, users){
    _.each(users, function(_user){
        user.findOneAndUpdate(
            {'_id' : user_id},
            {$inc : {'xxx' : yyy}},
        function(e){
            !e && pass()
        })

    })
})
}
```

Comment: It will always wait for a `for` loop.  It has to.

Comment: But I have to run that database process before `process2`.  Aren't there any solution? @Brad thanks.

Comment: That's what will happen with the code you have shown here.  `Process2` won't run until `callback` in the first closure is called.

Comment: What does your Process1 `for` loop do? Is it a series of DB calls? If not, then you can put the async to the db process.

Comment: In my experience this kind of code is easier to express using the promise model, they're a lot easier to chain.

Comment: @lwang135 I'm updating all users in DB in process1().

Comment: @Lazy Can you provide a code sample? Then I can perhaps provide a suggestion. EDIT: Nevermind you just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, `Process2` will definitely be called more than once, because `lodash` and `underscore` does not wait until the call back happens. They are just utilities methods.

To solve `asynchronous` situations like this, just use `async.each` or `async.eachSeries`.

```
function Process1(yyy, pass){
  user.find({}).exec(function(e, users){
    async.each(users, function(_user, next){
        user.findOneAndUpdate(
            {'_id' : user_id},
            {$inc : {'xxx' : yyy}},
        function(e){
            !e && next()
        })
    }, function(err) {
       pass();
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've understood the async usage thanks to you.